# Screen Share on TurboTax

Tags: .net, node.js, web-services, web, screensharing

I was just wondering what technology behind it. On TurboTax.com account section if you press Shift+Enter, A small popup appears on the right corner of the page for technical support to have access to your screen. It is more like a join.me share screen. Anybody knows what is behind it?

Comment: what does this have to do with .net or node.js?

Comment: not sure what language it is written with so I tagged with different possible languages. with nodejs they might be using websockets, with .net they might be using something similar. Because the question is about the technology I thought it makes sense to tag with them so people can see the question and may have an answer. didn't want to offend you :)

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

I found the answer for my question. If anybody interested in and end up on this question TogetherJS is the script they are using. It is developed by Mozilla Foundation and has an easy installation. The only bad part of it is if you are using a shared server and can not host your own websockets, you have to use their websocket server.

Another downfall I noticed is also other users can not see when you are interacting with dynamic form fields, like selectboxes, until you make a selection. So for a developer or support desk it is somewhat useful that can help to see what actually user is doing and having issues but it is definitely not a fully dependable product yet.